# How can I display WKT MultiLineString on OpenLayers in DJANGO project

Tags: python, javascript, openlayers, html, django

I want to display WKT in text on HTML. I wanted it on JS variable but i couldn't do that.

Python code

```
def showResult(request):
    
    start = request.GET['start']
    end = request.GET['end']
    .
    .
    .
    return render(request, 'showResult.html', {'name': MultiLineString})
```

showresult.html (temporary)

```
<body>
    <h1>user_type</h1>
    {{name}}
</body>
```

JavaScript code

```
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()});
var wkt = {{name}} //With this, it doesn't work it's not html i know that but i need same thing.
var feature = format.readFeature(wkt, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({source: new ol.source.Vector({features: [feature]})});

var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, vector,],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [3644045.5445922264, 4848151.403839435],
            zoom: 14.6
        })
        });
```

In this situation {{name}} get 'MULTILINESTRING((xx xx, yy yy),(aa aa, bb bb))'. If i get this on JS variable the problem would be solved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427964/how-to-display-wkt-multilinestring-on-openlayers-in-django-project